# Highcharts Bullet Chart with 2 x axes... possible?

Tags: graph, highcharts, double, bullet

I'd like to plot progress versus timeline on a 2 x-axis bullet chart.

See this JSFiddle for what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/ejhnnbk0/

```
Highcharts.chart('container3', {
xAxis: [{
        type: 'linear',
},{
        type: 'datetime',
        opposite: true
    }],
yAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
        from: 0,
        to: 14,
        color: '#f00'
    }, {
        from: 14,
        to: 20,
        color: '#ff0'
    }, {
        from: 20,
        to: 29,
        color: '#0f0'
    }],
    labels: {
        format: '{value}'
    },
    title: null
},
series: [{
    data: [{
        y: 16,
        target: 21
    }]
}],
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b> (with target at {point.target})'
}
});
```

What I am looking to implement is something like this, where a date range is on the top x-axis, and a numeric range is on the bottom x-axis. I'd like the bullet to represent progress (in this case, 16 out of 24), and I'd like the target line to indicate the current date in the date range (in this case, somewhere before 02/12/2018).

[image]

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Fist of all notice that your chart is `inverted` so you need to add another **y** axis (not x).

There're going to be 2 series: first that displays column (associated with first y axis) and second that displays target (associated with second y axis). In this case `grouping` has to be disabled (otherwise column and target won't be aligned properly).

Since there's no need to show target for the first series it's type can be changed to `column`:

```
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [{
      y: 16,
    }]
  }, {
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [{
      target: Date.UTC(2018, 0, 7)
    }]
  }]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e847jztb/

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I got caught up on the inversion!